# What does the Perl syntax <$VARIABLE> mean?

Tags: perl, sockets

Just can't find what this syntax (`<$SOCKET>`) does, although I guess it is some kind of default evaluation or behavior for the object inside the variable.

I was trying to test my Apache server (after installing the **mod_evasive** module) with this supposed-to-be DoS probe (this goes inside a 100-times loop), but it always returns a response **400 Bad Request**. Trying to decypher the code, I've got stuck with the commented line below.

```
use IO::Socket;
use strict;

my($response);
my($SOCKET) = new IO::Socket::INET( Proto   => "tcp",
                                  PeerAddr=> "127.0.0.1:80");
if (! defined $SOCKET) { die $!; }
print $SOCKET "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n";

$response = <$SOCKET>; ## What are those < > signs???

print $response;
close($SOCKET);
```

Then main interest I have is to be able of playing the test, so I need to know, first of all, why I get the 400 error code to fix it.

But also, BTW, for the sake of curiosity I'd like to understand the `<$SOCKET>` syntax meaning, because I can't find it explained anywhere.

Comment: See the documentation on [readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) and [the diamond operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)

Comment: My curiosity is satisfied, thank you. <b>&lt;$SOCKET> means "read from the SOCKET stream".

Comment: It doesn't though. The `<$handle>` means read a "line" from `$handle` whether the handle is connected to a socket or a simple file. Note also the difference between "_read a line from_" and plain "_read from_".

Answer (score 6):

The `< >` (also known as "the diamond operator") are a shorthand for `readline`. The thing inside the brackets provides lines of input. That could be a file handle, pipe, socket, or some other such thing. In your case, it's the variable `$SOCKET` that stores the socket you created.

A call to `<$SOCKET>` reads the next line from that input.

There's a bit of a trick though. In some other cases the `< >` is a shorthand for `glob`. If the thing inside the angles looks like a glob pattern, the `< >` returns the list of files that match that pattern:

```
 my @files = <*.txt>;
```

That's some old syntax that you might see; I prefer to spell it out though:

```
 my @files = glob( '*.txt' );
```

Comment: re "looks like a glob pattern", other way around; only a couple cases are treated as readline, almost everything else as glob

Answer (score 3):

- `<>` means `readline(ARGV)`
- `<IDENTIFIER>` means `readline(IDENTIFIER)`
- `<$IDENTIFIER>` means `readline($IDENTIFIER)`
- `<...>` (anything else) means `glob(qq<...>)`

You are using the third syntax, so `<$SOCKET>` means [`readline($SOCKET)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html). You are using it in scalar context, so it reads a line from `$SOCKET`.